# masking a video to show underlying still

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

I have a video - think Invisible man - I have created and animated 3 separate masks to show the background beneath which appears to work on the rendered window but do not work when I animate to the final movie clip as mp4.
I went into the composite window to set the nodes up.
What am I doing wrong?
I'm sure I've done this before with success.
Please help, it's driving me crazy
[image: image of screenshot attached]

Comment: Can you share some pictures of what you mean??cant comprehend

Answer (score 0):

I was using mix nodes to join the 2 layers. I order to do this you should use an Alpha Over node. My thanks to CGCookie for their posting on YouTube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eQst8SAVRE&t=3s
it is version 2.8 but did the trick for me. An added bonus was the multiple masking technique they showed.
I can't add a picture at this point as when posting it seems I overwrite the text so I'll comment afterwards with the screenshot.
Many thanks.
Rob.

[image: screenshot of the solution I found]